# dlib ImportError ( windows)

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning

I'm new dlib library and I'm having problem in importing the library in python. Whenever I try to run  python examples in windows, I get this traceback -

```
File "C:\Users\Shantanu\Desktop\dlib-18.12\python_examples\face_detector.py", line 30, in <module>
import dlib, sys
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I'm using Python 2.7.6 [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you compiled dlib? see and http://dlib.net/compile.html or http://sourceforge.net/p/dclib/mailman/message/26877083/

Comment: I have cmake and all the other necessary libraries installed for compilation

Comment: That error `%1 is not a valid win32 application` is windows telling you something important that you need to understand. It means windows is being told somewhere to run something that is not a valid binary. You should check your path, and check that whatever DLL is failing to load actually exists and actually is a valid DLL of the same bitness as your python. For example, you may have a 32 bit .PYD (which is really a DLL) that is found and being loaded into your 64 bit python 2.7 executable.